# bypassing .bashrc while rsync-ing a remote directory over ssh

Tags: rsync

Every once a while I manage to bork `.bashrc` on a server that I connect to over SSH. The errors sometimes mean I am `exit`-ed without a chance to edit `.bashrc`. In such cases, I connect with `ssh -t myuser@myserver bash --noprofile --norc`. However, rsync over SSH seems bent on executing `.bashrc`. When I try:

```
rsync -ravO -e "ssh -o IdentityFile=myrsaid bash --noprofile --norc" /localdir myuser@myserver:/myremotedir
```

I get:

```
 Could not resolve hostname bash --noprofile --norc: Name or service not known
```

How do I pass the `--noprofile` option to rsync?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't say the `rsync`, which shell to run on the remote side over `ssh`. It runs just the `rsync`.

You should rather not bork your `.bashrc`. SSH is running the `rsync` inside of the default shell (`bash`) without any special arguments.